# Animated movie where humans are hunted for sport

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

It's an old animated movie that has anthropomorphic characters and takes place in a city where humans are hunted for sport.

The animation style is similar to the movie "[The Cat Returns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gp-H_YOcYTM)"

Comment: This question is very sparse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you see this?  Where was it?  Who are the hunters?  (Monsters, aliens, robots, other humans...)

Comment: Maybe Fantastic Planet? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZB-MRPGvS0 Although I think the humans are exterminated as vermin rather than hunted for sport.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an adaptation of [The Most Dangerous Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Most_Dangerous_Game).

> Zaroff, another big-game hunter, knows of Rainsford from his published account of hunting snow leopards in Tibet. Over dinner, the middle-aged Zaroff explains that although he has been hunting animals since he was a boy, he has decided that killing big game has become boring for him, so after escaping the Russian Revolution he moved to Ship-Trap Island, which he has rigged with lights that lure passing ships into the jagged rocks that surround it. He takes the survivors captive and hunts them for sport, giving them food, clothing, a knife, and a three-hour head start, and using only a small-caliber pistol for himself. Any captives who can elude General Zaroff, Ivan, and a pack of hunting dogs for three days are set free.

It has been adapted many times in various formats.   [List of adaptations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_The_Most_Dangerous_Game)

Arguably the closest match from the list is :

> In the Disney animated series The Mighty Ducks "The Most Dangerous Duck Hunt" episode, the heroes are trapped on an island and hunted.

A reasonably close match, animated, with anthropomorphic animals as characters,  except that it's set on an island not a city.

does this look familiar?